# jobs list and finding the process ID using Linux in Red Hat

Tags: bash, redhat

I have wrote this script but when i run the job -ls and ps|grep i get no results here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'echo -e "kill Command given \n";exit 2'SIGINT SIGTERM
count=1
echo "start of the program"
while [ $count -le 10 ]
do
    echo "Loop #${count}"
    sleep 10
    count=$[ count + 1 ]
done
echo "end of program"
```

Comment: You should really be more specific as to what are you expecting. Are you wanting to detect the presence of your script, or the presence of the `sleep` command? What command, exactly, are you running, and what have you called your script?

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is invalid:

```
trap 'echo -e "kill Command given \n";exit 2'SIGINT SIGTERM
```

because you don't have valid spacing. Use this instead:

```
trap 'echo -e "kill Command given \n"; exit 2' INT TERM
```

You're probably doing something else wrong, too, since this works fine for me:

```
# Start 10 sleep processes in the background.
for x in {1..10}; do
    sleep 60 &
done

$ pgrep -c sleep
10
```

I'm getting the results *I'm* expecting, which is a count of the number of sleep processes currently running. If you're expecting something else, please update your question and provide some examples of your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```sh
ps | awk /$1/'{print $4; exit}'
```